# jQuery: Finding elements which contain certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have a calendar with an event list below it on my page. When the user clicks on the next or previous button, I want to populate a div with the contents of rows only containing the currently displayed month and year on the calendar. Here's the structure of the rows (created with Drupal 7 Views).

```
<div id="all-events">
  <div class="views-rows">
    <div class="field-date">
      <div class="field-content">
        <span>June 2011</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-rows">
    <div class="field-event-title">
      <div class="field-content">
        <span>Some Event</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got this far with jQuery, but I'm getting a huge list of errors:

```
   $('#calendar span.fc-button-next').live('click', function(){
      var month = $('#calendar .fc-header-title h2').html();
      $('.event-list').fadeOut(350, function(){
         $(this).html('');
         $('#all-events').each('.views-rows',function(){
            // Code goes here...
         });
      });
   });
```

I should also mention that I'm using FullCalendar to create the calendar, so it's created with this plugin. Right now I can get the current month the user is viewing, but I want to go through the list and find all rows that contain this month and display them in the .event-list div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems wrong:

```
$('#all-events').each('.views-rows',function(){...});
```

How about this:

```
$('.views-rows', '#all-events').each(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't fully understand what you want, but to filter elements by its text use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
<div>text 1</div>
<div> not this text </div>
```

JS

```
$("div").filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().indexOf("text 1") >= 0; // if contains desired text
}).html("this one matches 'text 1'");
```

**[See this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8jK/)**

Comment: It also replaces the divs when there are multiple divs that contain `text 1`, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8jK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.1.4, jQuery has a [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select elements containing a specific text.

```
$('#calendar span.fc-button-next').live('click', function(){
  var month = $('#calendar .fc-header-title h2').html();
  $('.event-list').fadeOut(350, function(){
     var event_list = $(this).html('');
     $('#all-events .views-rows:contains(' + month + ')').each(function(){
       event_list.append($(this).html);
     });
     event_list.fadeIn();         
  });
});
```